# Should bare questions like this be closed?

Tags: discussion

With some questions such as [this one](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8839/how-to-derive-density-mixture-in-two-phase-flow) it is difficult to know if there is enough context to answer the question - if there is any chance of someone with specialist experience being able to answer it.

The reason I ask is I was reviewing first posts and my impression is it should be closed, mainly because very little effort seems to have gone into it. Although perhaps it's a perfectly acceptable question.

I like to think that there should be enough information for someone without direct experience to do a bit of research in order to answer the question, but as it stands this would be hard.

On the other hand, perhaps if this site had 10 times the user base, it could make sense to defer such decisions to people with closer experience.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not the proper method for requesting closure on a question. If you have the requisite reputation, you may vote to close the question. If you do not have the VTC power, you may flag the question as potentially needing to be closed. For most questions, a specific discussion on the Meta is not necessary.

Comment: @TrevorArchibald, where should this question be asked, if not on meta?

Comment: If you think the question could be improved in some way, you should comment on the question itself or suggest an edit. And if you do just think it should be closed, either vote or flag it, depending on what your rep allows you to do. But imagine if every time someone looked at a question and wondered if it should be closed, they posted on the meta. There would be a meta discussion for every question. If it's a novel type of question that we can evaluate in a manner that applies to other questions, then a meta discussion is useful. But this is just an unclear question that needs more info.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance